# Alternatives to nested conditionals Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I have a page that presents bits of information in a grid format. What shows up in each grid tile depends on:

- Whether the user is logged in or not
- What the user clicks on
- Other factors

I'm using AJAX to send the controller what the user clicks on and grab fresh content for the tiles.

```
# Simplified pseudocode example
def get_tile_content
    tile_objects = []

    if current_user.present?
      if params[:user_selected_content] == 'my stuff'
        tile_objects = [... some model scope source here...]
      elsif params[:user_selected_content] == 'new stuff'
        tile_objects = [... some model scope source here...]
      elsif params[:user_selected_content] == 'other stuff'
        tile_objects = [... some model scope source here...]
      end
    else
      tile_objects = [... some model scope source here...]
    end

    render :json => tile_objects.to_json || {}
end
```

Any ideas on how to approach this differently? I tried moving the complexity to models but I found it to be less readable and harder to figure out what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a decent case for a `case` statement (...see what I did there? ;P)

```
def get_tile_content
    tile_objects = []

    if current_user.present?
      tile_objects = case params[:user_selected_content]
        when 'my stuff'    then Model.my_stuff
        when 'new stuff'   then Model.new_stuff
        when 'other stuff' then Model.other_stuff
      end
    else
      tile_objects = Model.public_stuff
    end

    render :json => tile_objects.to_json || {}
end
```

Sometimes case statements are necessary. Can't really say if that's the situation here since I can't see the larger design of your app, but this at least will clean it up a bit to fewer, easier to read lines, depending on your style preference.

You could wrap the case statement into its own method if you prefer, passing it the value of your parameter.

Another style point is that you don't typically use `get_` at the beginning of ruby method names. It's assumed that `.blah=` is a setter and `.blah` is a getter, so `.get_blah` is redundant.